# Is the "kill" command for job control the same as the "kill" command to send a signal to a process?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, job-control

In Linux, you can do the following:

`kill 1` (or `kill %1`)

Which means "close the processes in *job number 1*".

And you can do the following:

```
kill 1234
```

Which means "send the `SIGTERM` signal to the process with PID 1234".

Are these two `kill` commands the same command, or are they two different commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure you can do `kill 1` (or rather, you can try, but you won’t be allowed to, unless your root, and then you’re in for a surprise). `1` here always refers to the process with id 1, which is usually `init` (or some variant thereof).

To actually answer your question, if you’re in a shell which supports job control, `kill` will be a shell built-in, handling both cases (managing jobs and processes). See for example [Bash’s `kill` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins).

If you’re in a shell which doesn’t support job control (are there any?), `kill` will be a binary in the system, typically `/bin/kill`; see for example[`util-linux`’s `kill` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html). Even in a shell with a built-in `kill` command, you can access this one for example by specifying its full path. This `kill` command is also accessible without a shell (for use from another program).

See also [POSIX’s definition of `kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html), which covers both cases (but doesn’t specify what is implemented where).

Comment: (Yes, the Thompson shell.)

Comment: Hah @JdeBP, perhaps I should have said “in widespread use”!